# Alter a database table

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to alter a db table.

I want to alter the table specifically the row membership_id, status varchar(20), and a change the end date.

This is wp_pmpro_memberships_users table if anyone is familiar.

I want to keep the same membership_id which is 9 but update the status from expired to active and give it a new end date

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

J

Answer (score 0):

If your host has it available, you can edit the database directly using phpmyadmin. It is pretty common software if you are running a cPanel host. I would recommend taking a backup of your database before making alterations directly. But you can:

1. Select the database
2. Select the wp_pmpro_memberships_users table
3. Find the correct row and edit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ryan, this was to alter more than 1 row though.

I used....

UPDATE wp_pmpro_memberships_users
SET status = 'active'
WHERE membership_id = 12;

UPDATE wp_pmpro_memberships_users
SET enddate = '2021-04-17 15:00:00'
WHERE membership_id = 12;

Which worked :)

However I now want to move alter membership_id = 12; to membership_id = 21;

287 rows in this so doing one by one would take ages, there must be an alter to do this?